# 301 Redirect is only working without "www"

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

Redirecting is only working when redirecting to the domain without "www".

This is working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Using this redirect I get the error that there are too many redirections. How is that possible? I removed other redirections from .htaccess, but nothing changed.

Are there any server settings that may be the reason? (Unfortunately I don't have access to the admin area.)

Comment: Are you using both rules at the same time?

Comment: No, I tried them separately.